MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT not working for android 12 and up
These both code snippets not working for android version 12 and up for time validation in video recording.
I have tried these code snippets:
videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10)
videoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10)

But these are not working.
